# Executing programs on mobile phone

Tags: java, iphone, android

Hi I was wandering how do we execute programs on mobile phone...Not developing them!

Like I write a program to solve a particular problem. Now I need to install it on my mobile phone so that I can run the program on my phone anytime I need to do it. I am familiar with C#.NET (Windows Forms Application) and Java(Basic Console Applications). So anything that can be is good enough to run programs in these languages on mobile phone will help. My target mobile OS is primarily Android. But I also have an I-Phone. 
I am inclined more towards the C#.NET Windows form applications coz it is empowered with well-versed GUI

Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'm not exactly following -- do you want a program to be able to run the program, or do you want to?

Comment: no.For example : I have a windows application wherein I can add two numbers. Now I want to make that application work in my mobile as well. No matter how... I am OK installing a software that supports execution of my programs

Comment: You just weren't very clear, I'm guessing is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to execute the program from afar?  Look into C2DM framework on Android:
http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

You want to execute the program locally?  Tap the icon?

UPDATE:

Did I misinterpret your question?  If you want to do the majority in a different technology, perhaps you could have your Android Client work with a REST-based Web Service (Java or .NET).

If you take this approach, you could also make a lighter weight iPhone application that consumes the identical REST API.

Finally, you could look up Mono for Android (http://mono-android.net/).  I'd never heard of it before right now, but depending on your needs it might be worth considering.

Comment: I am not getting you. Can u please elaborate  so that i can understand?

Answer (score 1):

You're facing what is commonly referred to as a "cross-platform" problem. There are a few answers to how to get your program to run on a phone:

- Use a cross-platform language like Java (note there's no iPhone JVM)
- Make your app into a web app, most browsers can use those
- Use something like Adobe Flex
- Port it by hand (Original language to phone-specific language and SDK)

Each has its own advantages / disadvantages. It's impossible to give a better recommendation without knowing more details about the app in question.

Of course, I know that the answer you're *looking* for is some kind of emulator -- something that takes an existing program and "just runs it". You're very unlikely to find one on phones. PCs and phones are two very different platforms, and just because they're both technically computers doesn't mean that the code written knows how to effectively utilize the environment.

I hope someone steps in and makes me look like an idiot, I'd really love to know if such solutions DO exist. However from my own experience I've never seen anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Android and iOS mobile devices have different CPUs/processors and different OS's than your PC.  So you can't install and run PC apps on them.

You can either rewrite your apps using the Android or iOS/iPhone SDKs; or possibly run them on your PC and remotely view them using one of the various Remote Desktop or VNC apps.